# Convert csv to keyed json

Tags: php, json, csv

I have csv file that contains data like below without column headers

```
100271311,90445XXXX,Active
100271400,99456XXXX,Cancelled
100271552,94280XXXX,Pending
```

I want to convert the above to a php json output like below

```
{
   "100271311": {
      "FIELD2": "90445XXXX",
      "FIELD3": "Active"
   },
   "100271400": {
      "FIELD2": "99456XXXX",
      "FIELD3": "Cancelled"
   },
   "100271552": {
      "FIELD2": "94280XXXX",
      "FIELD3": "Pending"
   }
}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it:

```
  $file = file('pathtoyour/file.csv');
  $json = [];
  foreach ($file as $key => $row) {
    $cols = explode(',', $row);
    $json[trim($cols[0])] = [
      'FIELD2' => trim($cols[1]),
      'FIELD3' => trim($cols[2]),
    ];
  }
  die(json_encode($json));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$file  = "csvfile.csv";
$csv   = file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$json  = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

Note:
[str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) parses a string input for fields in CSV format and returns an array containing the fields read.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `file`, `explode` and `json_encode` functions:

```
$lines = file("./data/test.csv");  // change with your actual file path
$result = [];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list($k, $f2, $f3) = explode(',', $line);
    $result[$k] = ['FIELD2' => $f2, 'FIELD3' => trim($f3)];
}

print_r(json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

The output:

```
{
    "100271311": {
        "FIELD2": "90445XXXX",
        "FIELD3": "Active"
    },
    "100271400": {
        "FIELD2": "99456XXXX",
        "FIELD3": "Cancelled"
    },
    "100271552": {
        "FIELD2": "94280XXXX",
        "FIELD3": "Pending"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to convert csv to keyed JSON.

https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

There are a lot of options how you convert. Just choose conversion type button.